How to properly use BlockCV method of cross validation in dismo MaxEnt model in R?
This is what I have right now, but the model looks exactly the same as it does without the cross validation. The .html it spits out has no "training" data in the ROC curve or sensitivity specificity graph. I am very new to all of this.
# check spatial autocorrelation for quantitative basis for block size
cv_spatial_autocor(
  r = pop_density,
  x = all_points_sf,
  column = "presence",
  num_sample = 5000L,
  plot = TRUE,
  progress = TRUE,
)

# Spatial blocking for cross-validation
spatialBlocks <- cv_spatial(x = all_points_sf, 
                            column = "presence",
                            r = pop_density,
                            k = 5,
                            size = 408973, # Block size determined from spatial autocorrelation
                            selection = "random",
                            biomod2 = FALSE,
                            progress = TRUE,
                            iteration = 10,
                            plot = TRUE)
                            
# View blocks
plot(spatialBlocks$blocks)

# Running MaxEnt with k-fold cross-validation
cv_model <- maxent(x = env_vars, p = presence_vector, 
                   blocks = spatialBlocks$blocks,
                   factors = categorical_layers, 
                   method = "blockCV",
                   args = c("responsecurves=true", "pictures=true", "jackknife=true", "betamultiplier=1"))

# Check cross-validation results
print(cv_model)
plot(cv_model)


"the model looks exactly the same as it does without the cross validation" - have you given code for the model with and without cross-validation? Because its hard to tell from your post what is different to what. Is there another run of maxent with different parameters, because we probably need to see that too.

Also if you can show this with demo data that would help greatly, since then we can copy-paste your code to run it, saving us time to work on the actual problem.
